# why raspberry pi 3 fail to read 1000 p/r rotary encoder while my 8 bit nuvoton micro controller did that properly?

Tags: pi-3, interrupts, tkinter

I am using LS s40-6-1000ZT(H) 1000 p/r rotary encoder for my project with raspberry pi 3,but raspberry not working properly as per encoder specification(i.e not counting event properly).What could be the issue?
Any solution??

```
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
a=22
b=23
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(a,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(b,GPIO.IN)
root=tk.Tk()
clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)
def call():
   global clkLastState
   global counter
   clkState=GPIO.input(a)
   if clkState != clkLastState:
           dtState=GPIO.input(b)
           if dtState != clkState:
              counter +=1
           else:
              counter -=1
           text=str(counter/2)
           print (text[0:-2])
           var.set(text)
   clkLastState=clkState

def my_callback(channel):
   call()

counter=0
clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)
#GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
print (counter)
var=tk.IntVar()
L1=tk.Label(root,bg="orange",fg="red",textvariable=var)
L1.pack()
# var.set(counter)
# root.after(500,main)
root.geometry("100x100")
#GPIO.add_event_detect(22,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback,debouncetime=6)
root.mainloop()
#var=tk.IntVar()
#L1=tk.Label(root,bg="orange",fg="red",textvariable=var)
#L1.pack()  
#GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104425/discussion-on-question-by-ram-why-raspberry-pi-3-fail-to-read-1000-p-r-rotary-en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio has a more deterministic response to GPIO level changes.

Try my pigpio [Python example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py).

It requires the pigpio daemon.

`sudo pigpiod`

If Python can't keep up you will have to use C instead.  Perhaps try this [pdif2 C example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED).  It also use the pigpio daemon.

Comment: ,I tried with "pigpio Python example.".It work fine only to read but as per my application,I am showing that `pos value ` on tkinter.when i add tkinter part with your code ,then `pos value` reduced to approx 900 per rotation and more faulty count coming with anticlockwise direction.

Comment: I can't help with that.  I don't see that tkinter should affect the readings unless the system is almost overloaded.

Comment: ,there is nothing more on my system (i.e raspberry pi 3).only encoder reading and showing on tkinter window which contain 4 buttons and button function.Am i using tkinter in wrong way?Should i put tkinter part in another class like you create `class decoder` in your pigpio code?

Comment: ,thanks for your valuable suggestion.Only one issue coming in your ` Python example.`code i.e at of sudden it stuck and it start only after rebooting raspberry Pi.

Comment: is it for `decoder.cancel()` or `pi.stop` in the code?

Comment: The example code only runs for 300 seconds.  The __main__ code is an example of usage.  Use decoder.cancel() when you are done using the encoder and pi.stop() when your script has doe using pigpio.